# pandas - write a column of csv from pd.Series which is longer than row lines

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How to write or overwrite a column of csv from pd.Series, where the later is longer than original row lines? I use the following code:

`df.loc[:, col_name] = pd.Seriese(new_value)`

Where `col_name` is the column need to be modified, `new_value` is a list containing new values, this list is longer than table's row lines.

Then write csv with `df.to_csv(file_name, index=False, header=True)`

But it only writes original maximal rows of table.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `pd.concat`?

Before:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [2,3],
    [2,3],
    [1,5],
    [3,3]
], columns=['Test1', 'Test2'])

>>      Test1   Test2
   0    2       3
   1    2       3
   2    1       5
   3    3       3
```

Cast Series longer than number of rows into a DF:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[9,8,2,1,5],
    columns=["Test1"]
)
```

Concat remaining column(s) with `axis=1` to concatenate column-wise:

```
pd.concat([
    df2,
    df1[['Test2']]
], axis=1)

>>      Test1   Test2
   0    9       3.0
   1    8       3.0
   2    2       5.0
   3    1       3.0
   4    5       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! `pd.concat` works. However, there is a headache for me. For updating a column later, I need to keep this column's position in the table, so I have to pick up `left df` and `right df`, then concatenate the three together.